# setting value of dropdownlist

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu

I am trying to set the value of a dropdownlist using an integer id value from a table.  But whatever syntax I use (SelectedValue, SelectedItem, SelectedIndex), I keep getting a cannot convert int to string error.  Here is an example of my code :

```
ddlSupContracts2.SelectedItem.Value = Convert.ToInt32(ObjMeter.intSupplierContract);
```

ObjMeter.intSupplierContract will be an integer.  How do I use this value to set the selected item in my dropdownlist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
ddlSupContracts2.Items.FindByValue(ObjMeter.intSupplierContract.ToString()).Selected = true;
```

or

```
ddlSupContracts2.SelectedValue = ObjMeter.intSupplierContract.ToString();
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the value as a String instead of an  integer as `SelectedItem.Value` property is String type.

```
ddlSupContracts2.SelectedItem.Value = ObjMeter.intSupplierContract.ToString();
```

OR it can be

```
ddlSupContracts2.SelectedValue = ObjMeter.intSupplierContract.ToString();
```